# How to set a specific width for label in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to set a specific width for label in MVC?

The following method doesn't contain `HtmlAttributes` property.

```
@Html.Label
```

Note: I'm reading the width of the label from the controller.. It's dynamic.

Comment: Why not just write the ```<label>``` tag directly?

Comment: You could write your own HTML extension method and render the HTML yourself. Or use CSS styles to set the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `@Html.Label` does have a HtmlAttributes property.

So this should do it:

```
@Html.Label("my label", new {style = "width: 10px;"})
```

Comment: Are you sure?

I opened the Label definition and found the following overloads:

public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression);
public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression, string labelText);

Comment: What MVC version are you using?

Comment: Hm, your right, this was added in MVC4. A workaround would be to put a parent element around it and apply the width to the parent. Otherwise you could you just emit it directly instead of through the helper

Answer (score 1):

How about new {@class = "myclass"} and set the width in css?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a CSS for the label. so that one CSS can be abel to set width of all the labels